# How to configuring Taskserver 'max time limit' in MarkLogic Deployment Using mlgradle?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I'm working with mlgradle to deploy my MarkLogic application, and I'm trying to increase the 'max time limit' value for taskserver. However, I'm struggling to find a way to configure this via Gradle. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max-time-limit` is configured on the appserver, and the TaskServer is just a specialized appserver.

The taskserver configs live under: `/src/main/ml-config/task-servers/`
The appserver configs live under: `/src/main/ml-config/servers/`

In your TaskServer or appserver config file create an entry with the desired value. For a JSON file it would be something like:

```
"max-time-limit": 10800,
```

and for an XML config it would look like:

```
<max-time-limit>10800</max-time-limit>
```

If you take a look at any of the TaskServer or appserver configs through the Manage API, you can get an idea of what the fields are and the format in either JSON or XML:

For instance:

http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/task-servers/TaskServer/properties?group-id=Default&format=json
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/servers/Admin/properties?group-id=Default&format=xml
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/servers/Admin/properties?group-id=Default&format=json

Comment: Appreciate the response, @Mads. However, the details you provided are for configuring HTTP/XDBC servers. I'm specifically inquiring about Taskserver configuration.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that detail in your question. Same thing applies for the Task Server, http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/task-servers/TaskServer/properties?group-id=Default&format=json and creating a TaskServer config file: `/src/main/ml-config/taskserver/task-server.json`

Comment: Apologies, @Mads Hansen, it's my mistake. I've updated the title and description. Also, thank you for the second answer; it works, with a slight modification—the path is now /src/main/ml-config/task-servers/task-server.json.

Comment: can you please enrich your main answer to include the taskserver config?